Boy who can see EM waves but loses the ability because of a thunderstorm
I'm trying to find the name of a short sci-fi story in which a doctor discovers that a young boy can see electromagnetic waves with an extra organ in his head when he informs his father that the radio is broken because he can see the fault and where the electricity stops.
The boy has to wear lead earmuffs to protect the special organ and can never go out in a thunderstorm, he loses the ability when a girl removes the protection during a thunderstorm.
Do you know the book?

Obligatory snarky comment: most of us can see EM waves. Some of them, anyway...

This sounds very much like Child of Power, a short story by John Wyndham, first published in 1939.
A doctor discovers that a couple's baby is "radio-sensitive", that is, the child directly hears radio emissions. It was first discovered when the baby cried continuously, and only quietened when placed in a tin bath, which blocked the radio waves. Later, to enable the boy to live a normal life the doctor devised a Faraday cage arrangement by putting metal foil in the boy's cap, and earthing it with a wire going to the soles of his shoes.
The boy's father wants to take the boy on the music halls as a novelty act, "The Human Wireless". The doctor disagrees, especially when the boy reports hearing faint voices, which seem to be extra-terrestrial broadcasts. After a furious argument the boy is caught in a thunderstorm without his cap, and a flash of lightning permanently "blinds" his radio sensitivity.
